# How to configure hard drive

Tags: linux, partition, hard-disk, lvm

I have a hard drive that is not configured, it shows this in `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/dm-2: 107.4 GB, 107369988096 bytes 
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13053 cylinders 
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

How would I configure this, and mount it to `/var/t3`?

Also how would I make it stay configured in case of a reboot?

`dmsetup info /dev/dm-2` output:

```
Name:              tier3-tier3
State:             ACTIVE
Read Ahead:        256
Tables present:    LIVE
Open count:        0
Event number:      0
Major, minor:      254, 2
Number of targets: 1
UUID: LVM-9CdeuLeSVEJHBbjAJfFYRxxTfYYA0U5khb86NlUcyBAJC1JxP7FIhERCIoInYHLl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't look like a physical hard drive, more likely it's a LV (Logical Volume) or an encrypted partition or something like that. In any case it's being managed by Device Mapper (hence the `/dev/dm-` prefix).

Run `dmsetup info /dev/dm-2` and post the result here. We'll take it from there.

EDIT: Ok, it's a LVM volume. All you need now is:

1. Format it (unless it already is formatted)

   ```
   mkfs.ext4 -m0 /dev/tier3/tier3
   ```

   Make sure there are no existing data before formatting.
2. Add a record to `/etc/fstab` for after-reboot automatic mount:

   ```
   /dev/tier3/tier3  /var/t3   ext4   defaults   1 2
   ```
3. Try to mount it:

   ```
   mount -a
   df /var/t3
   ```

   and verify that the first column (Filesystem) shows tier3/tier3 volume

That's it.

Comment: It is a virtual hard drive. I have updated the question with the output.

Comment: @Petah - Thx. See my edit above for further steps.

Comment: It shows `/dev/mapper/tier3-tier3` is that correct? Seemed to work though

Comment: Yes that's correct. /dev/tier3/tier3 and /dev/mapper/tier3-tier3 are both symlinks to /dev/dm-2. Congrats, looks like it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
fdisk /dev/dm-2
n
p
1
```

Then i forget the next question but you'll want to use all the space you can, I think.

then:

```
fdisk -l /dev/dm-2
```

Find the name of the partition and run:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/dm-21
```

Or what ever your partition was named.

```
mount /dev/dm-21 /var/t3
```

Comment: If it's a LV or something similar you don't want to partition it again.

Comment: true enough. I didn't put two and two together with dm && device mapper